# How to display query data in two coloumns?

Tags: php

```
$query = $this->db->get("table_name");
foreach ($query->result() $row)
{
    echo $row->data;
}
```

It display the data like 
1 
2
3
4
I need in two coloums like 
12
34

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$nm = 0;
$str = '';

$query = $this->db->get("table_name");
foreach ($query->result() $row)
{
   $nm++;
   $str .= $row->data;
   if($nm%2==0){
    echo $str;
    $str = '';
   }
}
```

Comment: when you have three rows, only two are displayed. Technically your answer is wrong. http://hakre.wordpress.com/2012/02/28/some-php-iterator-fun/

Comment: @hakre maybe he want to igonre data that are single, because he said in two columns, not one or two

Comment: Since when can't two columns have a different length (very common). What you write obviously is a so called "lazy excuse" which sounds useless because it's more lazy to not give an answer than a technical wrong one. Don't get me wrong, "the remainder of" is useful in this context and part of your answer.